# Spring Cloud Feign with caching / eTag support

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, spring-cloud, etag, netflix-feign

I've been using Spring Cloud Feign and it's great.  But I'm noticing that the out-of-the-box behavior doesn't appear to employ client side caching -- such as eTags.

Is there a way to plug this behavior into Feign so that it has the same basic support for HTTP caching headers as your garden-variety browser?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Feign RequestInterceptors](https://github.com/Netflix/feign#request-interceptors) to modify they request any way you want.

Comment: Thanks Spencer.  As far as I can tell, though there is a RequestInterceptor, there is no ResponseInterceptor, and I need both to build eTag support.  Also, the HTTP handling code is hard-coded to consider any HTTP return code other than 200 as an error.

Comment: I do see some potential support for using HttpClient with Feign (https://github.com/Netflix/feign/tree/master/httpclient), and this would give me full eTag support.  However I'm not sure how to use this within Spring Cloud Netflix.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @KenKrueger there is a possibility, it would need a little work, at a glance it looks like you would need a `@Bean` of type `Client`.

Comment: that would be great.  Would you like me to make a feature request?  I can try it out if you want.  Also seems like other capabilities available in the Feign Builder might be desirable by other parties...

Comment: @KenKrueger there's a pull request I did today if you want to take a look. Don't remember the number.

Comment: Thanks Spencer.  I'll give that a shot when I come up for air in about a week.  If I understand the PR, I create a @Bean method that returns an instance of type of type feign.httpclient.ApacheHttpClient which in turn contains an instance of type org.apache.http.client.HttpClient, correct?

Comment: To customize it, yes. Otherwise it is autoconfigured if feign-httpclient is on the classpath

Comment: Please update the answer: now in 2018 if I want to have etags support for Feign how can I do it, is there an official documentation on it or even a better elaborated helpful article?